# Main diagonal into anti-diagonal

Tags: r, diagonal

I need to transform  main diagonal

```
{matrix(
1 1 1 1,
0 2 2 2,
0 0 3 3,
0 0 0 4)
}
```

into:

```
{matrix(
0 0 0 1,
0 0 1 2,
0 1 2 3,
1 2 3 4)
}
```

I tried all operators I could find `t()`, `arev()`, `flipud()`, `apply(x,2,rev)` and so on. Without a positive result. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Could you for those less versed in these things explain in words how you go from input to output?

Comment: `out <- matrix(0, ncol(m), nrow(m)) ; out[(col(out) + row(out)) > ncol(out)] <- m[upper.tri(m, TRUE)]`

Comment: x=1:100
y=101:200
q=matrix(0, 100,101)
q1=matrix(0, 100,101)
for(i in 1:100)
{
q[i:100-i+1,i]=x[i:100]
q1[1:i,i+1]=y[1:i]                                                                                        }                                                                                                                better this way?

Comment: @Nils; i dont know... can you show it for the small example in your question please. [PS if it is an answer, and youre happy it works, you should feel free to write it up in the answer section]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you? Takes each column and 'rotates' (for lack of a better word) x places, where x is the column index.

```
res <- sapply(1:ncol(input),function(x){
  #get relevant column
  base <- input[,x]
  n <- length(base)
  indices <- 1:n
  #reshuffle indices: first above x, then below x
  out <- base[c(indices[indices>x],indices[indices<=x])]
  out
})

all(res==output)
[1] TRUE
```

data used:

```
input <- structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), .Dim = c(4L, 
4L))
output <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4), .Dim = c(4L, 
4L))
```

Comment: thx, i could solve it an other way. is it possible to overwrite just parts of an matrix?   `x=1:100
y=101:200
q=matrix(0, 100,101)
q1=matrix(0, 100,101)
for(i in 1:100)
{
q[i:100-i+1,i]=x[i:100]
q1[1:i,i+1]=y[i:1]
q2=flipud(q1)
}
for(j in 1:100)
{
q[100-j+1:100,j+1]=q2[100-j+1:100,j+1]
}`